# Need help making a puzzle game

Tags: javascript

I'm using Perlenspiel to make a puzzle game and using Javascript with Sublime Text. The game is about the player controlling a snail and it leaves a trail of green slime that the player can't go through. The goal is to cover the white bead area with the green slime. I have most of the game set up and I just need help figuring out how to end the game and load up the next level after covering the area with green slime.

I'm new using Javascript and Perlenspiel and I'm not sure how to get it to work.

```
// Put your global variables after this line
var GRIDWIDTH, GRIDHEIGHT;
GRIDWIDTH = 11;
GRIDHEIGHT = 11;
var player = new Object();
player.x = 0;
player.y = 0;

// Put your function definitions after this line
function drawPlayer(x, y) {
  PS.color(x, y, PS.COLOR_GREEN);
  PS.glyphColor(x, y, PS.COLOR_WHITE);
  PS.glyph(x, y, "ඬ");
  player.x = x;
  player.y = y;
}

function drawSlime(x, y, dir) {
  PS.color(x, y, PS.COLOR_GREEN);
  PS.data(x, y, dir);
  PS.data(x, y, "wall")
}

function removePlayer(x, y) {

  PS.glyph(x, y, 0);
}


function isInGrid(x, y) {
  if (x < 0) return false;
  else if (x >= GRIDWIDTH) return false;
  else if (y < 0) return false;
  else if (y >= GRIDHEIGHT) return false;
  else return true;
}





// PS.init( system, options )
// Initializes the game
PS.init = function(system, options) {
  "use strict";

  // Use PS.gridSize( x, y ) to set the grid to
  // the initial dimensions you want (32 x 32 maximum)
  // Do this FIRST to avoid problems!
  // Otherwise you will get the default 8x8 grid

  PS.gridSize(GRIDWIDTH, GRIDHEIGHT); // replace with your own x/y values

  // Add any other initialization code you need here
  PS.statusText("Move:WASD Shoot:Arrow Keys")

  // Walls that The Snail can't pass through
  PS.color(7, 1, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(7, 1, "wall");

  PS.color(9, 1, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(9, 1, "wall");

  PS.color(10, 0, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(10, 0, "wall");

  PS.color(10, 10, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(10, 10, "wall");

  PS.color(8, 10, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(8, 10, "wall");

  PS.color(5, 4, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(5, 4, "wall");

  PS.color(10, 8, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(10, 8, "wall");

  PS.color(8, 8, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(8, 8, "wall");

  PS.color(0, 2, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(0, 2, "wall");

  PS.color(2, 3, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(2, 3, "wall");

  PS.color(2, 2, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(2, 2, "wall");

  PS.color(1, 0, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(1, 0, "wall");

  PS.color(0, 0, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(0, 0, "wall");

  PS.color(4, 4, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(4, 4, "wall");

  PS.color(4, 5, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(4, 5, "wall");

  PS.color(5, 5, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(5, 5, "wall");

  PS.color(10, 3, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(10, 3, "wall");

  PS.color(10, 5, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(10, 5, "wall");

  PS.color(4, 0, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(4, 0, "wall");

  PS.color(8, 5, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(8, 5, "wall");

  PS.color(3, 7, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(3, 7, "wall");

  PS.color(1, 9, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(1, 9, "wall");

  PS.color(4, 10, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(4, 10, "wall");

  PS.color(0, 5, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(0, 5, "wall");

  PS.color(1, 7, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(1, 7, "wall");

  PS.color(6, 7, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(6, 7, "wall");

  PS.color(6, 9, PS.COLOR_BLACK);
  PS.data(6, 9, "wall");


  // display The Snail's location
  drawPlayer(5, 0);
  PS.data(5, 0, "wall");
};

// PS.touch ( x, y, data, options )
// Called when the mouse button is clicked on a bead, or when a bead is touched
PS.touch = function(x, y, data, options) {
  "use strict";

  // Uncomment the following line to inspect parameters
  //PS.debug( "PS.touch() @ " + x + ", " + y + "\n" );

  // Add code here for mouse clicks/touches over a bead

};

// PS.release ( x, y, data, options )
// Called when the mouse button is released over a bead, or when a touch is lifted off a bead
PS.release = function(x, y, data, options) {
  "use strict";

  // Uncomment the following line to inspect parameters
  // PS.debug( "PS.release() @ " + x + ", " + y + "\n" );

  // Add code here for when the mouse button/touch is released over a bead
  //PS.color(x, y, PS.COLOR_GREEN);
  //PS.debug("You clicked on " + x + ", " + y + "\n");
};

// PS.enter ( x, y, button, data, options )
// Called when the mouse/touch enters a bead
PS.enter = function(x, y, data, options) {
  "use strict";

  // Uncomment the following line to inspect parameters
  // PS.debug( "PS.enter() @ " + x + ", " + y + "\n" );

  // Add code here for when the mouse cursor/touch enters a bead
};

// PS.exit ( x, y, data, options )
// Called when the mouse cursor/touch exits a bead
PS.exit = function(x, y, data, options) {
  "use strict";

  // Uncomment the following line to inspect parameters
  // PS.debug( "PS.exit() @ " + x + ", " + y + "\n" );

  // Add code here for when the mouse cursor/touch exits a bead
};

// PS.exitGrid ( options )
// Called when the mouse cursor/touch exits the grid perimeter
PS.exitGrid = function(options) {
  "use strict";

  // Uncomment the following line to verify operation
  // PS.debug( "PS.exitGrid() called\n" );

  // Add code here for when the mouse cursor/touch moves off the grid
};

// PS.keyDown ( key, shift, ctrl, options )
// Called when a key on the keyboard is pressed
PS.keyDown = function(key, shift, ctrl, options) {
  "use strict";

  // Uncomment the following line to inspect parameters
  // PS.debug( "PS.keyDown(): key = " + key + ", shift = " + shift + ", ctrl = " + ctrl + "\n" );

  // Add code here for when a key is pressed

  // WASD keys to move The Snail
  if (key == 119) {
    //Check that up isn’t a wall
    //Check that up isn’t off the screen
    if (player.y - 1 >= 0) {
      if (PS.data(player.x, player.y - 1) != "wall") {
        //If both are true, remove player from current position
        //If both are true, draw player in new position
        removePlayer(player.x, player.y);
        drawPlayer(player.x, player.y - 1);
        drawSlime(player.x, player.y);
      }
    }
  }
  if (key == 115) {
    //Check that down isn’t a wall
    //Check that down isn’t off the screen
    if (player.y + 1 < GRIDHEIGHT) {
      if (PS.data(player.x, player.y + 1) != "wall") {
        //If both are true, remove player from current position
        //If both are true, draw player in new position
        removePlayer(player.x, player.y);
        drawPlayer(player.x, player.y + 1);
        drawSlime(player.x, player.y);
      }
    }
  }
  if (key == 97) {
    //Check that left isn’t a wall
    //Check that left isn’t off the screen
    if (player.x - 1 >= 0) {
      if (PS.data(player.x - 1, player.y) != "wall") {
        //If both are true, remove player from current position
        //If both are true, draw player in new position
        removePlayer(player.x, player.y);
        drawPlayer(player.x - 1, player.y);
        drawSlime(player.x, player.y);

      }
    }
  }
  if (key == 100) {
    //Check that left isn’t a wall
    //Check that left isn’t off the screen
    if (player.x + 1 < GRIDWIDTH) {
      if (PS.data(player.x + 1, player.y) != "wall") {
        //If both are true, remove player from current position
        //If both are true, draw player in new position
        removePlayer(player.x, player.y);
        drawPlayer(player.x + 1, player.y);
        drawSlime(player.x, player.y);
      }
    }
  }

  // Keys to shoot the slime from the snail
  if (key == PS.KEY_ARROW_UP) // shoot up
  {
    if (isInGrid(player.x, player.y - 1)) drawSlime(player.x, player.y - 1, "up");

  }
  if (key == PS.KEY_ARROW_LEFT) // shoot left
  {
    if (isInGrid(player.x - 1, player.y)) drawSlime(player.x - 1, player.y, "left");
  }
  if (key == PS.KEY_ARROW_DOWN) // shoot down
  {
    if (isInGrid(player.x, player.y + 1)) drawSlime(player.x, player.y + 1, "down");
  }
  if (key == PS.KEY_ARROW_RIGHT) // shoot right
  {
    if (isInGrid(player.x + 1, player.y)) drawSlime(player.x + 1, player.y, "right");
  }

};

// PS.keyUp ( key, shift, ctrl, options )
// Called when a key on the keyboard is released
PS.keyUp = function(key, shift, ctrl, options) {
  "use strict";

  // Uncomment the following line to inspect parameters
  // PS.debug( "PS.keyUp(): key = " + key + ", shift = " + shift + ", ctrl = " + ctrl + "\n" );

  // Add code here for when a key is released
};

// PS.input ( sensors, options )
// Called when an input device event (other than mouse/touch/keyboard) is detected
PS.input = function(sensors, options) {
  "use strict";

  // Uncomment the following block to inspect parameters
  /*
    PS.debug( "PS.input() called\n" );
    var device = sensors.wheel; // check for scroll wheel
    if ( device )
    {
        PS.debug( "sensors.wheel = " + device + "\n" );
    }
    */

  // Add code here for when an input event is detected
};
```

Comment: What specific issues are you having trouble with? Asking us to complete a solution based on your own model doesn't sound fair unless you give us enough pointers.

Answer (score 0):

While this is the wrong approach for many reasons, a simple solution is to iterate through all values of `x` and `y` inside `PS.data` and check to see that every coordinate other than the current location of the snail has been set to be `"wall"`.

```
function boardCovered() {
  for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
      if(PS.data(x, y) != "wall")  //This is not the correct check - just an example. You need to figure this part out
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

I know nothing about Perienspiel but this will iterate your data structure and provide you with the correct result.